# Is there a way to make SVG shapes share a point array / shape? Can an SVG shape be defined in CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg, inline

I've been searching all around for this and found nothing.  Is it possible to make multiple SVG shapes share their shape by defining it in one place?  It seems to only be possible to define SVG shapes inline from everything I've seen.

For example:

```
//shape
<svg class="star" width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400">
<polygon fill="lime" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" 
        points="850,75  958,137.5 958,262.5 850,325 742,262.6 742,137.5" />
</svg>
<br>
//same shape
<svg class="star" width="12cm" height="4cm" viewBox="0 0 1200 400">
<polygon fill="lime" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" 
        points="850,75  958,137.5 958,262.5 850,325 742,262.6 742,137.5" />
</svg>
...
```

There are so many things wrong with inline definitions like this, I need not list them.

I'd like to be able to do this:

```
HTML
<svg class="star"><polygon /></svg><br>
<svg class="star"><polygon /></svg><br>
<svg class="star"><polygon /></svg><br>
<svg class="star"><polygon /></svg><br>
<svg class="star"><polygon /></svg><br>
<svg class="star"><polygon /></svg><br>
...
```

and then have everything defined in one place, like so.

```
CSS
.star {
  width: 12cm;
  height: 4cm; 
  viewBox: 0 0 1200 400;
}

.star polygon {
  fill: lime; 
  stroke: blue; 
  stroke-width: 10px; 
  points: [850,75  958,137.5 958,262.5 850,325 742,262.6 742,137.5];
   //I've tried quotes, no quotes, quotes around the numbers.
}
```

but so far nothing has worked, nor I have I found any examples or even a single link about something better, anything better, than defining the points inline.

There must be a better way!  Or perhaps I haven't tried the right syntax.

EDIT: this is as close to a thing as I've found: [svg patterns](http://designmodo.com/svg-patterns/)

Comment: You can definitely store the points in JS or JQuery. Do you only want to use CSS?

Comment: If at all possible.  I'm willing to use js, but I think it might obfuscate how the shapes are being defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple SVGs share items such points or even entire svg image.  Of the multiple techniques available, the one that most seems to do this as you have described is to use the svg "use" statement.

include something like this at the top of your page within the body

```
<svg class="star">
 <defs>
  <polygon id="poly1" fill="lime" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10"
   points="850,75  958,137.5 958,262.5 850,325 742,262.6 742,137.5" />
 </defs>
</svg>
```

then where you wish it to appear, use this statement.

```
<svg class="star" viewBox="0 0 1200 400">
 <use xlink:href="#poly1"></use>
</svg>
```

or if you want two of them

```
<svg class="star" viewBox="0 0 1200 400">
 <use xlink:href="#poly1"></use>
</svg>
<svg class="star" viewBox="0 0 1200 400">
 <use xlink:href="#poly1"></use>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can change the size of the SVG container in CSS and add the points to an array or object in JS or JQuery. You can play around with the demo to see if that works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var star = $('.star').find('polygon');
  var blob = $('.blob').find('polygon');

  var starObj = {
    points: '850,75  958,137.5 958,262.5 850,325 742,262.6 742,137.5',
    fill: 'lime',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: 10
  };

  var blobObj = {
    points: '800,75  900,137.5 958,262.5 700,325 742,262.6 742,137.5',
    fill: 'lime',
    stroke: 'blue',
    strokeWidth: 50
  };

  star.attr({
    'points': starObj.points,
    'fill': starObj.fill,
    'stroke': starObj.stroke,
    'stroke-width': starObj.strokeWidth
    
  });
  
    blob.attr({
    'points': blobObj.points,
    'fill': blobObj.fill,
    'stroke': blobObj.stroke,
    'stroke-width': blobObj.strokeWidth
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.star {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
.blob {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="star" viewBox="0 0 1200 400">
  <polygon fill="lime" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
<br>

<svg class="blob" viewBox="0 0 1200 400">
  <polygon fill="lime" stroke="blue" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>
```